# What does this jcl code do?

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

```
//ACTUPT EXEC PGM=finance.ACCTREC.UPDATE, REGION=1M,TIME=(,6),COND= (0,EQ, 
VALIDATE)
```

I understand this code allocates 1M of memory, the processor can take up to 45 seconds and that to make sure the return code equals zero. I do not understand "//ACTUPT" or "PGM=finance.ACCTREC.UPDATE". I think that what appears after PGM is the account name then the step name and the DDName but I would like to verify.

Answer (score 4):

This JCL contains a number of syntax errors, so it will simply result in a JCL error as written.

`REGION=` does not allocate memory, it limits the amount of memory that can be allocated.  1M is a ridiculously small region these days.

`TIME=` will limit the step to 6 seconds of CPU.

As it is coded, `COND=` will only execute this step if the condition code from the step named `VALIDATE` is not zero.

`ACTUPT` is the step name, the preceding `//` is syntactically required by JCL.

`PGM=finance.ACCTREC.UPDATE` is a syntax error, if it were written as `PGM=*.FINANCE.ACCTREC.UPDATE` it would indicate to execute the program in the temporary library named by the `DDNAME` `UPDATE` in the `ACCTREC` procstep and the step `FINANCE`.  Perhaps I led a sheltered career, but I've never before seen a `PGM=` parameter written this way.

Cleaning up syntax errors, I suspect we get...

```
//ACTUPT EXEC PGM=*.FINANCE.ACCTREC.UPDATE,
//          REGION=1M,TIME=(,6),COND=(0,EQ,VALIDATE)
```

I strongly suggest you familiarize yourself with the [IBM Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos).  JCL is under z/OS MVS in the table of contents.